# UITextView Cursor drag (long press magnifier glass) doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a UITextView, in which I can't see the long press text magnifier. Is there a way to force that magnifier to appear?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    BOOL isAtLeastOneGestureInlineTextView = [self isInlineTextView:gestureRecognizer.view] || [self isInlineTextView:otherGestureRecognizer.view];
    if ((gestureRecognizer == [self longPressGesture]) && !isAtLeastOneGestureInlineTextView) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (gestureRecognizer == [self panGesture]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isInlineTextView:(UIView *)view {
    return [view isKindOfClass:[SFGInlineTextView class]];
}
```

Apparently there was this check which disabled long press. To preserve former implementation, I've checked the gestures to not be the desired `textView`.